# Remover linhas em branco em um csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Eu estou tentando remover linhas vazias de um documento csv:

Documento:

> frase,lingua
>
> .,pt
>
> .,en
>
> .,en
>
> .,it
>
> .,es
>
> .,pt
>
> .,pt
>
> .,es
>
> .,pt
>
> .,pt
>
> "it's not expensive",en
>
> "casi 50 euros la alfombra es cara",es
>
> " o preço deve   baixar!!  ",pt
>
> " novos preços     por favor   ! ?? ",pt

Meu script:

```
import csv
import string

with open ("test.csv", "r") as f:
    csvfile = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ',')

    for line in csvfile:
        if line[1] == 'pt':
            frases = " ".join(line[0].lower().split()) 
            removePunct = "".join(word for word in mails if word not in string.punctuation)
            noEmptyLines = " ".join(lines for lines in removePunct if len(lines) != 0)

    print (noEmptyLines)
```

O resultado esperado:

> o preço deve baixar
>
> novos preços por favor

Meu resultado:

> n o v o s     p r e ç o s     p o r     f a v o r

Comment: Já tentou .strip() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for line in csvfile:
    if line[1] == 'pt':
        # Nesta linha, tomo a primeira coluna da linha do ficheiro CSV
        # troco a caixa das letras para minúscula e parto cada palavra
        # (atenção ao ' ', que é o caracter de partição), formando uma 
        # nova lista
        frase = line[0].lower().split(' ')

        novaspalavras = []
        for word in frase:

            # Nesta linha, tomo cada caracter da (palavra) variável 'word', 
            # contida em 'frase', comparo se é caracter de pontuação e, caso
            # não o seja, o caracter em questão é 'yieldado' para dentro
            # de uma lista de caracteres que, por sua vez, é tomada
            # pela função join de uma string vazia, ou seja,
            # a palavra será recomposta com "caracteres" de separação
            # vazios, tal como descrito na string que invoca join.
            novapalavra = "".join(char for char in word 
                        if char not in set(string.punctuation))

            if len(novapalavra) > 0:
                novaspalavras.append(novapalavra)

        # Nesta linha, recomponho a frase, emendando cada palavra com
        # strings " ", ou seja, espaços, intercalantes entre palavras
        # da lista.
        novafrase = " ".join(novaspalavras)

        # Nesta linha, caso a novafrase não seja vazia, ela é imprimida.
        if len(novafrase) > 0:
            print (novafrase)
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia,

Dado o "documento" e o código de exemplo, neste trecho:

```
if line[1] == 'pt':
    ...
```

Uma exception do tipo `IndexError`seria levantada para as linhas em branco contidas no documento.

O outro ponto que interfere no seu resultado esperado, é que no final do `loop for` você faz outro `join` e como strings em python são iteraveis o join percorre cada carctere da string e as une com um espaço.

O código abaixo cobre estes dois pontos de falha que detctei, e acredito que deva funcionar como o desejado.

```
with open("example.csv", "r") as f:
csvfile = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
for l in csvfile:
    if len(l) and l[-1] == "pt":
        if len(l[0]) > 1:
            removePunct = "".join(char for char in l[0] if char not in string.punctuation)
            print(removePunct)
```

Espero ter ajudado, e qualquer duvida quanto a solução estou a disposição!